# spring-data-jdbc error Required identifier property not found for class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Getting below error while loading data from database

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.sudhirt.practice.springdatajdbcpractice.entity.AuthorRef!

    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity.getRequiredIdProperty(PersistentEntity.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.readEntityFrom(EntityRowMapper.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.readFrom(EntityRowMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.lambda$createInstance$0(EntityRowMapper.java:167)
```

Below is the entity class `AuthorRef`

```
@Data
@Table("BOOK_AUTHOR")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthorRef {
    private Long author;
}
```

What might be the reason for above error?

Source code is available at https://github.com/sudhirtumati/spring-data-jdbc-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing `AuthorRef` in a `Set` inside your aggregate root `Book`.

```
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // ...

    private Set<AuthorRef> authorRefList;

    // ...
}
```

Without an id column Spring Data can't determine a primary key for `AuthorRef`.

Just adding an `@Id` annotation to `author` should be sufficient.

Alternatively you could use a `List` which will add an additional `book_key` column which together with the `book` column form a primary key.

Comment: Got error **Could not read property @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id()private java.lang.Long com.sudhirt.practice.springdatajdbcpractice.entity.AuthorRef.author from result set!** when annotated `author` with `@Id` annotation. Refer to sample repo commit id `18062a6`

Comment: When replaced set with a list, got error **Required identifier property not found for class com.sudhirt.practice.springdatajdbcpractice.entity.AuthorRef!**. Refer to commit id `47eacc8`

Comment: Thanks for providing the example repo. It looks like you hit one of those bugs we fixed for 1.1. With an update to the latest boot version both variants (List and Id) do work. See my PR for details: https://github.com/sudhirtumati/spring-data-jdbc-sample/pull/1